# Create Python virtual environment in forked, cloned repo, or clone repo into virtual environment?

Tags: python-3.x, github, virtual-environment

I've been using Github to host my own repos for a while, and I'm familiar with pushing changes to my own repos, but I've never worked on someone else's project. I'd like to try that now. I'd like to help someone with a Sphinx / reST documentation project.

The tutorial I'm following recommends creating a repo on Github, cloning the repo to my local computer, then creating a Python virtual environment inside of the cloned repo. However, the tutorial assumes the repo I'm working on is my own. In my case, it's not. I've forked the repo from someone else's account, and I'll have to make a pull request if I want to share my contributions.

Is creating the Python virtual environment inside of the forked, cloned repo really the right way to do this, or should I maybe create the virtual environment first, and then clone the repo into that instead?

It seems to me that if I create the venv folder inside of the repo, I'll have to be very careful not to accidentally include it in one of my commits. I'm not sure I can exclude files from a pull request after I've pushed them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> or should I maybe create the virtual environment first, and then clone the repo into that instead?

You don't want to put things into the virtual environment directory; this should be managed exclusively by Python's package management tools.

> It seems to me that if I create the venv folder inside of the repo, I'll have to be very careful not to accidentally include it in one of my commits.

You don't need to be careful. You just need to add your venv directory to your `.gitignore` file. For example, if I have a virtual environment in a `.venv` directory in my project, and I add that to my `.gitignore` file:

```
$ echo .venv/ >> .gitignore
$ git add .gitignore
$ git commit -m 'Ignore .venv file'
```

Then even if I try to add the directory explicitly it won't work:

```
$ git add .venv
The following paths are ignored by one of your .gitignore files:
.venv
hint: Use -f if you really want to add them.
hint: Turn this message off by running
hint: "git config advice.addIgnoredFile false"
```

> I'm not sure I can exclude files from a pull request after I've pushed them.

You can always update a pull request before it merges by pushing additional commits (or force pushing to replace existing commits). Look for articles about using `git rebase`.